# How do you keep your chillpad clean?

Tags: laptop, laptop-stands

You know that essential piece of functionality that sits just under your laptop so it doesn't overheat and die?  How do you keep dust and other evils out of it?

Comment: Simple: you don't use one.

I've never had overheating issues, and I don't use one on any of my three laptops.

Comment: @Fake Name You sound like a laptop salesman to me.  I don't believe you.

Comment: @leeand00 Hahaha.
well. I'm a bit of a sucker for technology, and I seem to inherit a lot of odd stuff from friends/acquaintances/random people. Right now, I have a Eeepc, a tablet (Fujitsu Stylistic), and a Sager DTR that I tend to leave at wherever I'm consulting, cause it's too big to carry around much.
Aside from cleaning out the interior lf your laptop every ~6 months, I've never had issues (well, except with a P4 based DTR I had once, but that was a design issue, not a dust issue).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Get a can of compressed air (aka "Duster"), and use it to blow the fans out regularly.  Use it on your notebook fans/vents as well.

Don't invert the can, don't spray it on yourself, and try not to inhale it. :)

[See here for a picture & description](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gas_duster).

Comment: Gag how could I not remember that!  Yup that works.

Answer (score 0):

[Air compressor.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Air_compressor)

Significantly more effective than canned air, because they're generally much higher pressure.

On the other hand, they're big, noisy and expensive, and most definitely not worth the effort unless you have a use for them outside of occasional cleaning.

On the other hand, if you know anyone who has a workshop, you can probably get access to theirs for long enough to use it.